# Calling a PHP function from within MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but essentially I want to have a function stored within my MySQL database, so here I have my database

```
Database->pages:
[id] [name ] [content ] [enabled] [main] [parent]
[6 ] [login] [login();] [1      ] [0   ] [5     ]
```

Now I'll have the set returned

```
public function viewPage() {
        global $db;
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT content
        FROM pages
        WHERE id = :getid
SQL;
       $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
       $resource->execute( array (
       ':getid'    =>   $_GET['id'],
       ));
       foreach($resource as $row){
               echo $row['content'];
       }
}
```

Last but not least I have my viewPage.php page that has

```
$static->viewPage();
```

So when I go to viewPage.php?id=6 I want it to pull the data and since content is login(); I want it to call the login(); function which would be translated into an include file. Is this even possible?

Comment: you can look at the eval function http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: You should not be doing that, really.

Comment: @NikolaPetkanski, While I appreciate constructive criticism what you gave there is simply a statement. If you put forth the effort to say you shouldn't do it then you should also feel free to give your reasoning behind it. Otherwise to me it seems to me the same as "Dogs are better than cats" It's at this point only a statement with no facts behind it, simply an opinionated statement. I'm not trying to be rude it just doesn't make sense to me to say anything at all.

Comment: There's a saying among developers. It goes like "eval() is the root of all evil.". If you are to be saving a php code in mysql and you are to be executing it later on, I really doubt this is by design. More likely there's a problem with the software architecture and the feature you are working on has not been engineered properly.

If you are unaware of what I am saying after this comment, there's really nothing I can do to make it more clear. Gaining experience you may be able to grasp it in a few years.

I don't mean to be rude. English is not my native language and people often complain. :)

Comment: No not rude. Makes sense, the way I work the code is so that a shorthand code can be thrown into the database then pulled if there's a function that matches. That gives me more to go on then it shouldn't be done at all. I've never cared when people simply post a one sentence statement and feel that they've contributed whereas there you've clarified what you meant to where I can look into why you think it's a bad idea. I don't mind doing the research on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) to achieve this effect. We would need to verify that the function [`is_callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) beforehand.

Let's say we get a row back with the field `name` set to `login`. You can do this:

```
if( is_callable($row['name']) )
    $row['name']();
```

This will call the function `login`. You can also pass parameters if you want, as you would any other function.

Comment: Awesome Answer! Exactly what I needed. Works exactly like what I had in mind. `public function viewPage() {
  global $db;
  $query = <<<SQL
  SELECT content
  FROM pages
  WHERE id = :getid
SQL;
 $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
 $resource->execute( array (
  ':getid' => $_GET['id'],
  ));
   foreach($resource as $row){
     if( is_callable($row['content'] ))
     $row['content']();
    else
     echo $row['content'];
   }
 }` makes it so that it now can either call the content or the function.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to create a whitelist of functions instead of dropping the name directly in the DB. Otherwise if your DB is compromised all kinds of interesting things could happen. Better yet would be to use an event system as it solves that problem and also probably offers added utility to your application as a whole.

Comment: I do strongly agree with @prodigitalson. That is the next step to take. Heed their words. ;)

Comment: I'll have to do more reading on that later on down the road. My original thought was I wanted to do a shortcode system. IE [login] and [login] would be used to call an actual function and I still want to eventually go that route, but at this time I'm not quite there.

Comment: It wouldn't be too bad, actually! You can have an array of whitelisted functions and then check if the field from the row is in that array. If so then it is callable and you can skip the `is_callable` check entirely, so it would still be two small lines of code. :)

Comment: Would it be better to go the blacklist route? IE. take all the functions within the base and blacklist them? Eventually I want to make it so other people can make functions (Modules) for what I'm working on.

Comment: There are a lot of built-in PHP functions, almost all of which would need to be blacklisted. I personally prefer the whitelist option--you can always add to the list when necessary. There will almost certainly be less functions to whitelist than blacklist.